# How to make animations with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, module, transition

I'm new to this forum :)

I'm learning python, so far I can make programs without much effort, I'm planning to make a program where it shows a window with some animations when it detects an event, for example, if I press a key the window shows a nice "icon" with some nice transitions and disappears.

which module should fit perfect for this task? I want to work with nice icons made on Illustrator.

Something like this page but the fact is I don't want to make it on a web browser.

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Animated-Interactive-Donut-Chart-with-jQuery-Snap-svg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a helpful python module(very famous), you have most likely heard of it. [Pygame](http://pygame.org). There are many alternatives, but by far Pygame is the most popular. Another animation module(mostly used for math) is [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/). Really effective for data science.

Comment: I don't personally use Matplotlib much though. I use Pygame more

Answer (score 0):

Or if you are the fan of ASCII Art - https://asciimatics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/